# Make a POST request with JQuery to c# .net rest API

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, rest

I am trying to make an ajax post request to a backend server that is built with .net framework. The backend is a REST API built with c# .net.
When i try to make a POST request with postman everything goes well, but when i try to do it with ajax, i dont get any data on the backend.
This is the C# code:

```
public Documento()
        {
            this.DocContabilidade = new Dictionary<string, string>()
            {
            };
            this.Linha1 = new Dictionary<string, string>()
            {
            };
            this.Linha2 = new Dictionary<string, string>()
            {
            };
            this.Linha3 = new Dictionary<string, string>()
            {
            };
        }
 public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] Documento documento)
    {
        
        Console.WriteLine(documento);

        // (when I make the request with postman the var has data, when i do it with ajax its empty)
        .
        .
        var response = Request.CreateResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Created, "a");
        return response;
    }
```

when i try to send an object with postman, like I said it works well.
this is the postman data, its the same i send with ajax.

```
 {
        "doccontabilidade": {
            "ano": "2020",
            "doc": "411",
            "diario": "22",
            "mes": "09",
            "dia": "30",
            "moeda": "EUR",
            "modulo": "L",
            "descricao":"FT54011481",
            "num_doc_externo": "54011841"
        },
        "linha1": {
            "tipo_linha": "F",
            "conta": "211110001",
            "natureza": "C",
            "moeda": "EUR",
            "tipo_entidade": "F",
            "entidade": "FVD",
            "valor": "529,02",
            "valor_alt": "529,02",
            "valor_origem": "529,02",
            "descricao": "FT 9999",
            "lote":"1"
        },
        "linha2": {
            "tipo_linha": "F",
            "conta": "31211",
            "natureza": "D",
            "moeda": "EUR",
            "tipo_entidade": "F",
            "entidade": "FVD",
            "valor": "430,1",
            "valor_alt": "430,1",
            "valor_origem": "430,1",
            "descricao": "FT 9999",
            "lote":"2",
            "iva":"12132311"
        },
        "linha3": {
            "tipo_linha": "F",
            "conta": "24321132311",
            "natureza": "D",
            "moeda": "EUR",
            "tipo_entidade": "F",
            "entidade": "FVD",
            "valor": "98,92",
            "valor_alt": "98,92",
            "valor_origem": "98,92",
            "descricao": "FT 9965",
            "lote":"3"
        }
    }
```

this is the response from postman:
[postman response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cx9nz.png)

the ajax request is as follows:

```
var dados = {
    "doccontabilidade": {
        "ano": "2020",
        "doc": "411",
        "diario": "22",
        "mes": "09",
        "dia": "30",
        "moeda": "EUR",
        "modulo": "L",
        "descricao":"FT54011481",
        "num_doc_externo": "54011841"
    },
    "linha1": {
        "tipo_linha": "F",
        "conta": "211110001",
        "natureza": "C",
        "moeda": "EUR",
        "tipo_entidade": "F",
        "entidade": "FVD",
        "valor": "529,02",
        "valor_alt": "529,02",
        "valor_origem": "529,02",
        "descricao": "FT 9999",
        "lote":"1"
    },
    "linha2": {
        "tipo_linha": "F",
        "conta": "31211",
        "natureza": "D",
        "moeda": "EUR",
        "tipo_entidade": "F",
        "entidade": "FVD",
        "valor": "430,1",
        "valor_alt": "430,1",
        "valor_origem": "430,1",
        "descricao": "FT 9999",
        "lote":"2",
        "iva":"12132311"
    },
    "linha3": {
        "tipo_linha": "F",
        "conta": "24321132311",
        "natureza": "D",
        "moeda": "EUR",
        "tipo_entidade": "F",
        "entidade": "FVD",
        "valor": "98,92",
        "valor_alt": "98,92",
        "valor_origem": "98,92",
        "descricao": "FT 9965",
        "lote":"3"
    }
}
```

Ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "https://192.168.33.122:44395/api/movimento",
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(dados),
        dataType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (response) {
            alert(response["resultado"])
        },
        failure: function (response) {[enter image description here][1]
            console.log('Erro');
        }
   });
```

and this is the response from ajax:
[ajax response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXJZ5.png)

I tried to send the data without the JSON.stringify but C# still cant detect anything.

Comment: Might want to show in your post what `dados` is. Have you tried: `data: { documento: dados }` in your `ajax`? Use the parameter name in your data object.

Comment: If the JS is running on a different domain to `https://192.168.33.122:44395` then you will be being blocked by CORS. In any case you need to check the console to find an error to debug

Comment: @ryan Wilson, sorry i thought it was implied, the var dados hás the content i am sending with postman but i Will edit it.

Comment: @rory i have cors enabled on the server side that is not an issue.

Comment: @patrickarsenio Cool. Thanks. Have you tried my suggestion and have you debugged the error portion of your `ajax`?

Comment: @ryanwilson i dont get any error on the ajax call.

Comment: @patrickarsenio Did you try: `data: { documento: dados }` in your ajax?

Comment: @ryanwilson just did, same result

Comment: @RyanWilson i just posted an image with both requests responses, its not the best way to show it but i dont know how else i could do it.

Comment: @patrickarsenio Have you checked the `Network` tab of your browser to see how the body of the post request is being presented to the server? `ajax` is hitting the endpoint I assume?

Comment: @RyanWilson yes i did, i get a response from the server 201, everything is ok on this side.

Comment: instead of `data: JSON.stringify(dados)` try `data: dados`. you are setting the content type to application/json. there should be no need to stringify

Comment: @Trekco i tried both ways and none of them works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I do it and is working is:

```
var dados= { dados: [... your elements ...]};

        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'Your-URI',
            data: JSON.stringify(dados),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            cache: false,
            traditional: true,
            success: function (response) {
            alert(response["resultado"])
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                console.log('Erro');
            }
        });
```

or

```
$.ajax({
    url: "@Url.Action("Your-METHOD", "Your-Controller")",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify({ dados: Documento}),
    traditional: true,
    success: function(response) {
        response ? alert("Processing") : alert("Error");
    }
});
```

and in backend

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<JsonResult> JsonResponseMessage(Documento doc)
.....
```

It is better if the document data structure is the same as the response data json.
You can convert the json response with [JsonToSchemaC#](http://json-schema.org/)
Hope it helps.

Comment: Why should they install a package? How is this going to help? Be specific.

Comment: I'd suggest you read the question title again, at least.

Comment: @RyanWilson okay, if you more detail.. wait

Comment: Before you do that, your answer does not address the question. Read the question again - OP wants to make a request to C# API ***from jQuery***. As such I'd suggest you delete this answer instead.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan ohhh yeah sorry, I just saw. wait, I will update again.

Comment: @Zeta Now you changed your answer to use `C#`, this isn't going to solve the OP's question.

Comment: @RyanWilson check it

Comment: @Zeta I got it working now using your sugestion to do a JsonToSchemaC#